# ¿Qué método utilizar para reiniciar una base de datos con patrones?

Tags: mysql, eclipse

Estoy realizando una actividad en la que interactuo con una base de datos desde eclipse con JDBC. El problema que tengo, es que para realizar la prueba de los método que realizo tengo que estar todo el rato reiniciando a mano la base de datos. Por lo que se me ocurrió hacer un método que la reinicie directamente antes de realizar los tests de cada método. Es ahí donde me falla, he probado numerosos ejemplos y ninguno me ha dado buen resultado.
Actualmente utilizo este, que si lo ejecuto una vez se realiza bien, pero si lo ejecuto por segunda vez ya me da error.

```
    public void reiniciarBaseDatos() {
ScriptRunner sr = new ScriptRunner(con);
try {
    sr.setLogWriter(null);
    sr.runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/sql/creaTablas.sql")));
    System.out.println("Se ha reiniciado correctamente la base de datos");
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error al reiniciar la base de datos");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}
Y en el pom.xml, tengo añadidas sus respectivas dependencias.

```
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
<artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
<version>3.4.5</version>
```

Comment: Estas haciendo pruebas unitarias?

Comment: Si, estoy haciendo los respectivos test de cada método

Comment: Las pruebas unitarias no hacen uso de ningún recurso externo como bases de datos, sistema de archivos, peticiones http, etc. Si se está probando el código con una base de datos real entonces no son pruebas unitarias, son de integración. Estás usando el patrón repositorio en tu aplicación?